# Group Strings In List By Maximum

Tags: scala

Have been trying to tackle this problem in scala, but can't quite get it figured out.

I have a `List[String]`, and want to group the different Strings together so that no group exceeds a maximum size, keeping a note of their index in the list.

Here is some sample data as an example:

```
val sample: List[String] = List[String](
    "{\"test\":\"testfield\"}", // 20 length
    "{\"test2\":\"testfield2\"}", // 22 length
    "{\"test3\":\"testfield3\"}") // 22 length

val maxLength = 48 // collect into groups where total .length is less than this

val output: List[List[Int]] =
    List(
        List(0,1),
        List(2)
    )
```

I have managed to simulate the same thing in Java, but trying to replicate this in Scala style code without for loops is trumping me. I have current been trying using `scanLeft`.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is essentially linewrapping and has been answered before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122150/scala-muliline-string-split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version using `foldLeft`:

```
def groupByLength(list: List[String]): List[List[String]] = {
  list.foldLeft(List(List.empty[String])) { (acc, cur) => 
    if (acc.isEmpty) List(List(cur))
    else if (acc.last.map(_.length).sum + cur.length < maxLength) acc.init :+ (acc.last :+ cur)
    else acc :+ List(cur)
  }
}
```

For your sample it returns:

```
List(
  List({"test":"testfield"}, {"test2":"testfield2"}), 
  List({"test3":"testfield3"})
)
```

For an even better version, one could use a `NonEmptyList` to guarantee that the resulting List is inhabited.

If you want to return the indices of the list instead, you could `zipWithIndex`beforehand.